# Systematic way to find a matrix that satisfies an equation

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

*Background*

It is relatively easier to find a solution to a system of linear equations in the form of $A\textbf{v}=\textbf{b}$ given the matrix $A$. But what systematic ways are there that allows us to obtain a matrix given a equation?

For example, consider the following equations with all terms existing in $\mathbb{R}$

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a&b&c\\
d&e&f\\
g&h&i\\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}2\\3\\4\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}
$$

Although it is easy to see that $a=\frac{1}{2}, e=\frac{1}{3}, i=\frac{1}{4}$ with all other terms being $0$ is a viable solution,
**I am curious if there is a more systematic way of finding a matrix that satisfies a equation.** Even more importantly, **how should these methods be adapted when there are added constraints on the properties of the matrix? For example, if we require that the matrix of interest should be invertible, or of rank = $k$?**

*Why I am interested in such question*

Consider the vector space $P_2{(\mathbb{R})}$, the problem of finding a basis $\beta$ such that $[x^2+x+1]_\beta = (2,3,4)^T$ can be reduced to a problem that has been stated above.

Comment: Why are you interested in this question? What are your thoughts on it resp. your attempts?

Comment: $A \textbf v= \textbf b$ where $A$ is a linear map, which maps $\textbf v$ to $\textbf b$ and maps every other vector $\perp \textbf v$ to vector $\perp \textbf b$ or $\textbf 0$. So $A$ can be decomposed to $A_2A_1$ where $A_1$ maps $\textbf v$ to $ \textbf b$ and $A_2$ has eigenvector $\textbf b$ with eigenvalue 1.

Comment: @James
The reason I am interested in this question is added in the question. Well my attempts have been multiplying the same matrix to both sides but it has been of no real value

Comment: @ZangMingJie Can you elaborate more?

Comment: If you are searching for a basis, the matrix needs to have full rank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as $A\mathbf v=\mathbf b$ is equivalent to a system of linear equations in the entries of $\mathbf v$, it can also be equivalent to a system of linear equations in the elements of $A$. In particular, you have $$\begin{align}2a+3b+4c&=1\\2d+3e+4f&=1\\2g+3h+4i&=1,\end{align},$$ or in matrix form, $$\begin{bmatrix}2&3&4&0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&2&3&4&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0&2&3&4\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\\e\\f\\g\\h\\i\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\end{bmatrix}.$$ I expect that you know how to find the general solution to these equations. Indeed, it’s possible to write one down from the matrix form of this system by inspection.